# How to ignore 'the' when sorting WordPress categories alphabetically

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

I have a site which shows a long list of events, which the user can filter by date and by venue. The events are setup using Events Manager Pro and we're using the Event Categories for the Venues.

In the search form for the events, the Venues (categories) appear as a drop-down, in alphabetical order. We would like to keep them in alphabetical order but ignoring 'The' at the start of any venue names so, for example, 'The Frog and Fiddle' would appear under F rather than under T.

Events Manager Pro allows for customisation of template files so I've copied the relevant file into the relevant folder-tree in my child-theme; this is the code from that file:

```
<?php $args = !empty($args) ? $args:array(); /* @var $args array */ ?>
<!-- START Category Search -->
<div class="em-search-category em-search-field">
    <label>
        <span><?php echo esc_html($args['category_label']); ?></span>
        <?php 
            EM_Object::ms_global_switch(); //in case in global tables mode of MultiSite, grabs main site categories, if not using MS Global, nothing happens
            wp_dropdown_categories(array( 
                'hide_empty' => 0, 
                'orderby' =>'name', 
                'name' => 'category', 
                'hierarchical' => true, 
                'taxonomy' => EM_TAXONOMY_CATEGORY, 
                'selected' => $args['category'], 
                'show_option_none' => $args['categories_label'], 
                'option_none_value'=> 0, 
                'class'=>'em-events-search-category'
            ));
            EM_Object::ms_global_switch_back(); //if switched above, switch back
        ?>
    </label>
</div>
<!-- END Category Search -->
```

I found this solution: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/216929/ignoring-initial-articles-like-a-an-or-the-when-sorting-queries - which creates a custom orderby function which ignores 'The' when sorting:

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', function( $orderby, \WP_Query $q )
{
    // Do nothing
    if( '_custom' !== $q->get( 'orderby' ) )
        return $orderby;

    global $wpdb;

    $matches = 'The';   // REGEXP is not case sensitive here

    // Custom ordering (SQL)
    return sprintf( 
        " 
        CASE 
            WHEN {$wpdb->posts}.post_title REGEXP( '^($matches)[[:space:]]+' )
                THEN TRIM( SUBSTR( {$wpdb->posts}.post_title FROM %d )) 
            ELSE {$wpdb->posts}.post_title 
        END %s
        ",
        strlen( $matches ) + 1,
        'ASC' === strtoupper( $q->get( 'order' ) ) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC'     
    );

}, 10, 2 );
```

However, this is geared towards posts rather than taxonomies and I'm unsure how to repurpose it to apply to categories rather than posts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way 1: Using slugs as orderby parameter:

You can do it with small trick.

1. remove "the" from taxonomy slugs.(strings which appear at URL)
2. Change orderby parameter from name to slug.

   ```
          <?php wp_dropdown_categories(array( 
               'hide_empty' => 0, 
               'orderby' =>'slug', 
               'name' => 'category', 
               'hierarchical' => true, 
               'taxonomy' => EM_TAXONOMY_CATEGORY, 
               'selected' => $args['category'], 
               'show_option_none' => $args['categories_label'], 
               'option_none_value'=> 0, 
               'class'=>'em-events-search-category'
           ));
   ```

Way 2: Setting custom orderby:

```
  function custom_meta_order($dropdown) {
  $dropdown['orderby'] = "ORDER BY REPLACE(t.name,'The ','')";
  return $dropdown;
}
add_filter('terms_clauses','custom_meta_order');
```

Comment: Hi Elvin, 

Thanks for this, although I'd prefer not to go down that route if possible - the events are created in a google spreadsheet which autopopulates from a number of forms the venues fill out themselves, and new venues are added quite frequently.  

Long story short, the Venue as taxonomy is generated from the Venue name, which needs to appear as-is on the site, so this method would require a number of changes to that process and/or manually making the change to remove 'the' from the slugs - I'm ideally hoping for a solution which I can just set and forget.

Comment: ok i understood your case. but removing starting "the " string from the slug is easy, "set and forget" thing. You have insert script, you can inject this small operation there and forget about it. But if you don't want to do it anyway, i will add an update to my question with alternative solution.

Comment: Sorry - I could have been clearer there. By 'set and forget' I meant something that would apply to all potential future venues which might be added, so this isn't something we have to consider each time (& it's not something I know how to automate at any stage of the process). 

Thank-you so much for adding the second solution - it's worked perfectly! Cheers for your help :-)

Comment: Hi Elvin, 

Sorry to come back to this so much later. I've just realised this piece of code is conflicting with the re-ordering ability of the Co-Authors Plus plugin, and I'm unable to change the order of multiple authors. 

Is there a way to limit this code snippet so it either only applies to the 'event category' custom taxonomy, or doesn't apply to authors? 

Thanks!